# Django: How to put submitted data back in the form (update functionality)

Tags: python, django

I have been trying to make an 'update function' in my table so that my data can be changed by a user.

So here is my html with the form where i want my data to go back in to, so when the user presses submit again it saves that value to the database:

```
 <h3>Add a location </h3></br></br>
      <div class="addition">
        <form method="POST" action="" autocomplete="off">
          {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Location name" name="name" autocomplete="off">
              
              </div>

              <div class="col">    
                <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Description" name="desc" autocomplete="off">
                
              </div>
              <div class="col">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                
              </div></br></br>
             
        </form> </br></br>

    <h3>Overview locations</h3>


      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-striped table-sm">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>#</th>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Description</th>
              <th>Description</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {% for item in all_locations %}   
                <tr>                    
                <td>{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.desc }}</td>
                <td><a class="btn btn-sm btn-info" href="{% url 'update_location' item.id %}" >update</a></td>
              </tr>
```

my **views.py** with my creation function and my update function

```
def location(request):
    all_locations = Location.objects.all()
        if request.method == "POST":
            loc_form = LocationForm(request.POST or None)

            if loc_form.is_valid():
                loc_form.save()

            return render(request, 'location.html', {"all_locations": all_locations})

    else:
        return render(request, 'location.html', {"all_locations": all_locations})
    return render(request, 'location.html', {"all_locations": all_locations})





def updateLocation(request, pk):
    all_locations = Location.objects.all()
    location = Location.objects.get(id=pk)
    loc_form= LocationForm(instance=location)
    name = loc_form.instance.name
    desc = loc_form.instance.desc
    print(name)
    print(desc)
    return render(request, 'location.html', {"all_locations": all_locations, "name": name, "desc": desc})
```

my **models.py**

```
class Location(models.Model):
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=None)
    desc =  models.CharField(max_length=250, default="", null=True, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

and my **urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.index, name="index"),
path('locations', views.location, name="location"),
path('locations/<str:pk>', views.updateLocation, name="update_location"),
]
```

So basically i'm stuck at putting the old data back into the html input.
I've tried with a different view as well but i had basically the same issue.

Any suggestions? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out whilest doing something else:

add `value="{{ name }}"` to the html file on the input line. Do the similar thing for description